# Rmpi: cannot use MPI_Comm_spawn API

Tags: linux, r, parallel-processing, mpi

I installed Rmpi on my linux machine and it successfully loads in R.  There are two versions of MPICH on my machine, and I (believe) have installed Rmpi with the latest version.  I also had to update my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.  I primarily followed the installation instructions [here](http://www.stats.uwo.ca/faculty/yu/Rmpi/install.htm).

After loading Rmpi in R, I run `mpi.spawn.Rslaves(nslaves=4)` and get the following error message:

```
Error in mpi.spawn.Rslaves(nslaves = 2) : 
You cannot use MPI_Comm_spawn API
```

Does anyone know how I can get Rmpi working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use MPICH2 for spawn support. If you have MPICH2 installed, you may still need to specify `--with-Rmpi-type=MPICH2` when installing Rmpi. If you used `--with-Rmpi-type=MPICH` instead, it would disable functions such as `mpi.spawn.Rslaves`.

Also note that MPICH2 apparently does not support spawning workers unless the program is launched using a command such as mpiexec. This basically means that you can't execute `mpi.spawn.Rslaves` from an interactive R session using MPICH2, although this is possible using Open MPI. To be clear, this is not the issue that you're reporting, but you may encounter this after you have correctly installed Rmpi using MPICH2.

I was able to install Rmpi 0.6-5 using MPICH 3.1.3 with the command:

```
$ R CMD INSTALL Rmpi_0.6-5.tar.gz --configure-args='--with-mpi=$HOME/mpich-install --with-Rmpi-type=MPICH2'
```

To debug a configuration problem, you should install Rmpi from a directory rather than a tar file. That will allow you to examine the "config.log" file afterwards which will provide important information. Here is how I did that on my Linux box:

```
$ tar xzvf Rmpi_0.6-5.tar.gz 
$ R CMD INSTALL Rmpi --configure-args='--with-mpi=$HOME/mpich-install --with-Rmpi-type=MPICH2'
```

In order to get spawn support, the `MPI2` macro needs to be defined when compiling the C code in Rmpi. You can check if that is happening by searching for "PKG_CPPFLAGS" in config.log:

```
$ grep PKG_CPPFLAGS Rmpi/config.log
PKG_CPPFLAGS='-I/home/steve/mpich-install/include  -DMPI2 -DMPICH2'
```

I have found "config.log" to be very useful for debugging configuration and build problems.

Note that you can use Rmpi without spawn support. You'll need to start all of the workers using mpirun (or mpiexec, etc) and it will be much more difficult, if not impossible, to use functions such as `mpi.apply`, `mpi.applyLB`, etc. But if you just need to initialize MPI so you can use MPI from functions implemented in C or Fortran, you will probably need to start all of the workers via mpirun.

Comment: Is there a specific version of MPICH2 I need to use? I downloaded version 1.5 from mpich.org and I'm having trouble installing the Rmpi package with it.

Comment: @Rich To use mpi.spawn.Rslaves, you need to use a version of MPI that supports MPI 2.0. I've always used Open MPI which has no problem supporting spawning in Rmpi. My guess is that you're running into an Rmpi configuration problem when building with MPICH2 which is causing spawn support to be disabled, but it's hard to solve it without looking through your configuration messages.