# Tell Rstudio to use mpif90 instead of gfortran

Tags: r, rstudio, r-package

In order to learn how to create a R packages that uses Fortran I created [a simple one to calculate Pi with a monte carlo simulation](https://github.com/ignacio82/MyPi). Now I'm trying to make the Fortran code parallel with MPI.

When I add `use MPI` to my fortran code and click the `Build and Reload` buton on Rstudio I get the following error.

```
==> R CMD INSTALL --no-multiarch --with-keep.source MyPi

* installing to library ‘/home/ignacio/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2’
* installing *source* package ‘MyPi’ ...
gfortran  -fpic -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong  -c  Fpi.f90 -o Fpi.o
/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:161: recipe for target 'Fpi.o' failed
** libs
Fpi.f90:2.4:

  use mpi
1
Fatal Error: Can't open module file 'mpi.mod' for reading at (1): No such file or directory
make: *** [Fpi.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘MyPi’
* removing ‘/home/ignacio/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/MyPi’
* restoring previous ‘/home/ignacio/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/MyPi’

Exited with status 1.
```

I think the problem is that Rstudio is trying to compile using gfortran instead of mpi90. I'm able to follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28491478/call-parallel-fortran-mpi-subroutine-from-r) to do a very basic hello world, but there you compile the code with `mpif90 -fpic -shared -o test.so test.f90`

How can I tell Rstudio to use `mpif90 -fpic -shared` instead of `gfortran`?

---

I added this to `src/Makevars`

```
 FC=mpif90
```

This is what I get:

```
==> R CMD INSTALL --no-multiarch --with-keep.source MyPi

* installing to library ‘/home/ignacio/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2’
* installing *source* package ‘MyPi’ ...
gfortran  -fpic -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong  -c  Fpi.f90 -o Fpi.o
/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:161: recipe for target 'Fpi.o' failed
** libs
Fpi.f90:2.4:

  USE MPI
1
Fatal Error: Can't open module file 'mpi.mod' for reading at (1): No such file or directory
make: *** [Fpi.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘MyPi’
* removing ‘/home/ignacio/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/MyPi’
* restoring previous ‘/home/ignacio/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/MyPi’

Exited with status 1.
```

Comment: Try setting `FC=mpif90` in your `Makevars` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set the `FC` flag in your `Makevars` file to indicate the fortran compiler you wish to use.

```
FC=mpif90
```

**EDIT - The above doesn't work if included locally in your package**

The `FC` macro will be overwritten when specified within a package `Makevars` because the `src/Makevars` file is read before `$RHOME/etc/Makeconf` which overwrites the `FC` macro. In order to change the default compiler is to create a Makevars file in a `.R/` directory in your `$HOME` directory.

Then just create the file with the same line as above.  Restart R and try to compile again (this worked on my Ubuntu system).

Comment: my bad... is not working :( I updated my question to reflect that

Comment: @Ignacio are you on Windows?  If so, you need it to be in your `Makevars.win` file.

Comment: Ubuntu (to be more precise I'm running this on docker with `rocker/hadleyverse` )

Comment: Your edit did not work either :( . I updated my question showing that. Thanks!

Comment: `.R` not `R` directory.  It is a 'hidden' directory

Comment: Great! That works!!. Is the fact that `src/Makevars` is not working a bug? Should I report it? If so, do you know how?

Comment: I cannot confirm that it is a bug, it may be intentional.  That question may be more appropriate for the [R-package-devel](https://www.r-project.org/mail.html) or R-devel mailing lists where someone more likely to understand the R internals could answer that.